# Monodevelop: change startup configuration

Tags: mono

I have the known problem with MonoDevelop where the debugger cannot connect, when I try to run the debugger. Now I found a solution in the post [Monodevelop doesn't run the project. When I try to run nothing happens](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120685/monodevelop-doesnt-run-the-project-when-i-try-to-run-nothing-happens) I have to call `unset KDE_SESSION_VERSION` before I run MonoDevelop and everything works fine. Now the problem, I cannot start the application with the MonoDevelop icon because there, I assume, the `unset KDE_SESSION_VERSION` line is not called. So my question can I create a script or something so that the line above is called automatically before the MonoDevelop is called, so that the debugger works?

**Further information:**
The MonoDevelop icon is the application icon, which is e.g. shown in the start menu. 
OS: Linux arch 4.8.8-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 17 14:51:03 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux. For the gui KDE Plasma 5 is used.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify further what this "MonoDevelop icon" is. Is it a KDE icon?

Comment: @ojs I have update my question. Is this enough information for you?